# Unique/Smart Pointer Vector in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stack, heap-memory

I am practicing using a smart pointer (in c++). And I am really stuck on a question:[image]

I need to code this representation, where normally one box represents the smart pointer, and the arrow points to a heap variable.
In this question, the boxes are together, therefore it represents a vector of smart pointers.
I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work.
Here is what I try so far:

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<char>>> ptr_vec;
ptr_vec -> push_back(make_unique<char>('w'));
```

If I run it just say my program stop working
If I go in debug I get this (it open the file vector.tcc and showed me this):
[image]

but then I am unable to assign addresses to the unique_ptr

Comment: Please show the code that you tried and the error that you got.

Comment: You have a pointer to a vector. Where is the part where you create a vector and make your pointer point to it? Do you know that pointers point to other things and you have to actually create the thing before you can use it?

Comment: You have a (unique) pointer to a vector of (unique) pointers. This does not make much sense in practice. Why not just a vector of pointers?

Comment: According to the diagram you don't want a vector at all, because it's elements are stored on the heap. If you want to store them on the stack a `std::array<std::uniqe_ptr<char>, 9>` seems better suited

Comment: Thank you I understand now!! I will take out my first unique_ptr!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of `unique_ptr` initially holds no value; it needs to be initialized first:

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<char>>> ptr_vec;
ptr_vec = make_unique<vector<unique_ptr<char>>>();
```

Otherwise `ptr_vec->push_back()` will access a null pointer and the program will crash with a segmentation fault like you're observing.

But a pointer to a vector here is unnecessary, just `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char>>` is enough:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<char>('w'));
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<char>('-'));
    vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<char>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<char>('*'));
    // . . .
}
```